# Distinct column values in csv file

Tags: csv, distinct-values

I have a csv file.
columns in csv file - "SNo. StateName CityName AreaName PinCode NonServ.Area MessangerService Remark".
The column CityName has repeated values.

Ex: In many records, it has unique value (Delhi).
Is there any approach in java to read that csv file and get the distinct values from that column of the csv file.

Comment: correction "Ex: In many records, it has **repeated** value (Delhi)."

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: No connection to database. I will read from many csv files only.

Comment: why don't you create temparory `.csv` file that fullfils your requirement. create temporary csv file using `SELECT unique(cityname) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/temp.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table_name;` Reference https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/select-into.html

Comment: I think using HashSet is better, because it won't allow duplicates into it. And no need to create a temporary csv file. So, creating a HashSet with all the records from csv file would return a distinct column values.

Comment: Yes, If you don't have any rights to do changes with DB then as suggested by kojow , do it with "Hashset"

Comment: I can't access database. I tried it with HashSet. It is working fine now. Thanks fro your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to do it row by row and store each value into an array-type structure. Using a set structure such as HashSet or TreeSet will ensure unique values.

The other option, which isn't what you were looking for but might work depending on your project is to use a database instead of a csv file. It then becomes very easy to select distinct values in a column.

Comment: I can't use a database connection. I can use only csv files. I'll try with the hash set implementation. Hashset won't allow duplicates. I think it is better approach.

Comment: I have done using HashSet and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

df is where you've read csv data

```
df[CityName].unique()
```